# Gson deserialize map of csv rows

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I have a json api response that is structured similar to a csv file

```
{
    "headers": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "row1": [1, 2, 3],
    "row2": [4, 5, 6]
}
```

I need to get a POJO for each row in that json object

Ideally I'd like to declare it like

```
class Row {
    @SerializedName("a")
    Integer a;

    @SerializedName("b")
    Integer b;

    @SerializedName("c")
    Integer c;
}
```

So my question is, can I write a custom deserializer so that I can do something like this? It would also be useful to serialize the other direction as well.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();  
List<Row> rows = gson.fromJson(apiResponse, new List<Row>());
```

Comment: "a","b" and "c" are values for key "header", you want to serialize on value instead of key?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but I want to use the values in the "header" key as the field names for the corresponding positions in each row. The other keys are meant to be ids for each Row object

Comment: so what will be the values for "a", "b" and "c"?

Comment: the object for "row1" would have a=1, b=2, c=3. You could express the same data as normal json like
[ { "a":1, "b":2, "c":3 }, { "a":4, "b":5, "c":6 } ]

Answer (score 0):

The problem not in deserialization.
My way to solve your issue.

1. Use defaulet deserializers for parsing.
2. Use [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) to convert parsed lists to objects